# Maven 3: Stripes Archetype - cannot create project?

Tags: maven, stripes, maven-archetype

I'm following this guide:

http://www.stripesframework.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1572995&decorator=printable

I run the following command, which reports BUILD SUCCESS:

> mvn install:install-file 
>   -Dfile=stripes-archetype-quickstart-1.0.jar 
>   -DgroupId=net.sourceforge 
>   -DartifactId=stripes-archetype-quickstart 
>   -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

I had previously downloaded the file "stripes-archetype-quickstart-1.0.jar" from here :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mvnstripes/files/stripes-quickstart-1.0/1.0/stripes-archetype-quickstart-1.0.jar/download

So far so good, now I continue with the guide and attempt to create a project based on the archetype with this command:

> mvn archetype:generate 
>   -DarchetypeArtifactId=stripes-archetype-quickstart 
>   -DarchetypeGroupId=net.sourceforge
>   -DarchetypeVersion=1.0

But Maven doesn't appear to recognize the newly installed archetype; and it goes into interactive mode:

> Your filter doesn't match any archetype (hint: enter to return to
>   initial list) Choose a number or apply filter (format:
>   [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): :

Is there a trick I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use option "-DarchetypeCatalog=local" when referencing local archetype, e.g.

```
  mvn  archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

Answer (score 1):

with `-DinteractiveMode=false` will solve the issue